# Compile kendo window after refresh content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-window, kendo-template

I have a single **kendo-window** in my page and i want to load content to it every time i click a command. The content i want to load is either from **x-kendo-template** or from **.html** with expression in angular *{{Sample}}*. After the content is loaded, i tried to $compile the content to make use of the angular binding but it is not working. This is what i tried so far

On my markup

```
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular">

<script id="tplAddNew" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    Action in Add New: {{ Action }}
</script>

<script id="tplView" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    Action in View: {{ Action }}
</script>

<div id="example" ng-app="Test">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div kendo-window="winTesting"
            k-visible="false"
            k-modal="true"
            k-pinned="true"
            k-width="'500px'"
            k-min-height="'200px'">
        </div>

      <button 
          kendo-button 
          ng-click="AddEntry()">Add Entry</button>
      <button 
          kendo-button 
          ng-click="ViewContent()">View Content</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my controller

```
var app = angular.module("Test", ["kendo.directives"]);
app.controller("MyCtrl", [
    "$scope", "$compile",
    function($scope, $compile) {
        $scope.AddEntry = function() {
            $scope.Action = "Add New";

            $scope.winTesting
                .refresh({
                    //url: '../References/Test-entry.html'
                    template: kendo.template($('#tplAddNew').html())
                })
                .setOptions({
                    title: "Create New User"
                });

            //$scope.$apply(function() {
            //    $compile($scope.winTesting.element)($scope);
            //});

            $scope.winTesting.open().center();
        }

        $scope.ViewContent = function() {
            $scope.winTesting
                .refresh({
                    //url: '../References/View-entry.html'
                    template: kendo.template($('#tplView').html())
                })
                .setOptions({
                    title: "View User Detail"
                });

            //$scope.$apply(function() {
            //    $compile($scope.winTesting.element)($scope);
            //});

            $scope.winTesting.open().center();
        }
    }
]);
```

lets assume that the content of **Test-entry.html** is the same as **tplAddNew** Template

Now, when i will use the **$compile** function, it will show an error of **$apply already in progress**

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

i also prepared a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdagpin/fm2vh5gt/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo has not really refined this widget yet.  So in light of that use the $timeout service:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $compile($scope.winTesting.element)($scope);
}, true);
```

The last boolean parameter does (more or less) a $scope.$apply.  [See the Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

#### Edit:

There is also some cool stuff you could do with the $parse service as well.  [You might find it useful as explained in this blog](https://umur.io/advanced-angular-parse/)

Comment: Hi... it works on the template scenario.. however, its not working on url.. so i think there is a chance that retrieving value from URL will take longer that $timeout executes.. is there any solution to this? like event after the url is completely downloaded

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this.. because i am using url method, this solution will not work. What i did is i put it in refresh event of the window and is now working good.

Comment: You could put the content into the $templateCache.  Is the template dynamically generated on a server?

Comment: It is not.. its just a plain html tags, expression and kendo template which is stored in different html file.. **insert.html**, **view.html**, **update.html**

Comment: You know, considering your requirements I would just wrap the kendo directive in your own directive.  That way you could retrieve the template with $http (and its built in promise) and then manually control the $compile function before returning it to kendo.  Note:  you may have to use k-ng-delay during this process.

Comment: Or just put template retrieval and compilation functionality into a service and inject that into your controller.  Though, I still think your best bet is to use the $templateCache either way.